# Save wpf view as image, preferably .png

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0

I have [searched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx#_wpfImaging) and understand how to save an image in WPF by using `BmpBitmapEncoder`. My program has a MVVM view that I want to save as an image. Is it possible to set it as `BitmapFrame` so I can encode it? If so, is there an online tutorial?

Listed below is the view I want to save.

```xml
<Grid>
    <view:OverallView Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="{Binding IsOverallVisible,Converter={StaticResource B2VConv}}" />
</Grid>
```

`OverallView` is a user control.

---

If setting a view as a `BitmapFrame` is not possible, what wpf elements can be set as a `BitmapSource/Frame`?

Comment: Does this post help? http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can return it as [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx):

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(OverallView view)
{
    Size size = new Size(view.ActualWidth, view.ActualHeight);
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(view), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
        context.Close();
    }

    result.Render(drawingvisual);
    return result;
}
```

After that you can use the [PngBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx) to save it as PNG and save it to stream, e.g.:

```
public static void SaveAsPng(RenderTargetBitmap src, Stream outputStream)
{
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));

    encoder.Save(outputStream);   
}
```

FIX: bitmap => result

Comment: Change bitmap to result. Other than that, its fine.

Comment: The `src` parameter can be `BitmapSource` to make it more widely usable . Also the encoder local varaiable should be declared var imho.

Comment: I didn't get how to call these methods, could anyone explain me? Tks.

Comment: @Denis, you can see my answer below.  The  above has unnecessary logic in it which I've removed. I also made it into an extension method with examples showing you how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to the accepted answer above for leading me down the path to a solution, but that's actually over-complicating the requirements.  Specifically, you don't need to create a `DrawingVisual` to pass to the `Render` call. You can pass the view directly since it's already a `Visual`, which the `Render` call accepts.

Here's a simplified version that I've also changed into an extension method on `FrameworkElement` so you can use it easily with any control.

> Note: Although `Render` accepts a `Visual`, you can't extend `Visual` since you need the actual width and height to create the `RenderTargetBitmap`, but chances are for that same reason you're probably already using a `FrameworkElement` anyway.

```cs
public static RenderTargetBitmap? CopyAsBitmap(this FrameworkElement frameworkElement) {

    var targetWidth  = (int)frameworkElement.ActualWidth;
    var targetHeight = (int)frameworkElement.ActualHeight;

    // Exit if there's no 'area' to render
    if (targetWidth == 0 || targetHeight == 0)
        return null;

    // Prepare the rendering target
    var result = new RenderTargetBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    // Render the framework element into the target
    result.Render(frameworkElement);

    return result;
}
```

I then have a second extension method that takes any `BitmapSource` (which `RenderTargetBitmap` is a subclass of) and returns the bytes based on the provided encoder.

```cs
public static byte[] Encode(this BitmapSource bitmapSource, BitmapEncoder bitmapEncoder){

    // Create a 'frame' for the BitmapSource, then add it to the encoder
    var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
    bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);

    // Prepare a memory stream to receive the encoded data, then 'save' into it
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmapEncoder.Save(memoryStream);
    
    // Return the results of the stream as a byte array
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

And here's how you use it all together. This code renders any `FrameworkElement` as a PNG:

```cs
var renderTargetBitmap = someFrameworkElement.CopyAsBitmap();
var pngData = renderTargetBitmap.Encode(new PngBitmapEncoder());
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\TestOutput.png", pngData);
```

Or more fluently...

```cs
var pngData = someFrameworkElement
    .CopyAsBitmap()
    .Encode(new PngBitmapEncoder());

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\TestOutput.png", pngData);
```

To instead render it as a JPG, just change the encoder, like so...

```cs
var jpegData = someFrameworkElement
    .CopyAsBitmap()
    .Encode(new JpegBitmapEncoder());

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\TestOutput.jpg", jpegData);
```

Additionally, since `RenderTargetBitmap` is ultimately an `ImageSource` (via `BitmapSource`), you can also set it as the `Source` property of an `Image` control directly, like so...

```cs
someImage.Source = someFrameworkElement.CopyAsBitmap();
```