# WPF Apply image MatrixTransform to source

Tags: wpf, image, export, bitmapsource, matrix-transform

Suppose I have WPF Image control, with underlying BitmapSource. Several transformations are applied to image, using MatrixTransform (scale and translate). Is there any way I could apply those transformations to original image and then save it as it looks on screen?

Problem is that I cannot just "screenshot" image and export, because quality is lost. So what I thought is that I could apply those transformations to original image but with larger size so that quality would be preserved.

Unfortnuately I do not know if i am on any kind of right track so any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: You could use the RenderTargetBitmap class to convert a visual into a bitmap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560173/save-wpf-view-as-image-preferably-png

Comment: Thanks @mm8 I will try but as I already stated, visually image control is small and quality is lost when rendering to image. Will try anyways though